# Web scraping in Python with selenium. selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, python-3.9

[What I am trying to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o53Ga.jpg) I have tried changing the sleep time and time_between_checking. It returns on the first iteration and then fails in the while loop. Why would the By.CSS selector execute correctly the first time the get_first_listing function is called and then fail the second time?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
import os

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

os.environ['WDM_LOG_LEVEL'] = '0'
s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(s=path, options=chrome_options) # if you have problems with line 15

# Setting
classified_link = 'https://classifieds.ksl.com/search/Furniture'
time_to_wait_between_checking = 15


def get_first_listing():
    driver.get(classified_link)
    time.sleep(15)
    link = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#search-results > div > section > div > div:nth-child(1) > '
                                                'section:nth-child(4) > div.listing-item-info > h2 >'
                                                ' div > a').get_attribute('href')
    title = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#search-results > div > section > div > div:nth-child(1) >'
                                                 ' section:nth-child(4) > div.listing-item-info > h2 > div > a').text
    return (link, title)


listing_info = get_first_listing()
first_listing_link_temp = listing_info[0]
listing_title = listing_info[1]

print(f"First Listing Title: {listing_title}, Link: {first_listing_link_temp}")

check_count = 0
active = True
while active:
    check_count += 1
    time.sleep(time_to_wait_between_checking)
    print(f"Checking to see if new listing, this is attempt number {check_count}")
    new_listing_info = get_first_listing()
    first_listing_link = new_listing_info[0]
    title = new_listing_info[1]
    if first_listing_link_temp != first_listing_link:
        print(f"There is a new ad. Title {title}, Link: {first_listing_link}")
        active = False
        break
```

The output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:PATH.py", line 46, in <module>
    new_listing_info = get_first_listing()
  File "C:PATH.py", line 26, in get_first_listing
    link = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#search-results > div > section > div > div:nth-child(1) >'
  File "C:PATH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 856, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:PATH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 429, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:PATH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#search-results > div > section > div > div:nth-child(1) > section:nth-child(4) > div.listing-item-info > h2 > div > a"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=106.0.5249.119)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
...

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Website is blocked by 'Press & Hold' captcha.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here to make your code start working:

1. You have to close the cookies banner.
2. Need to introduce `WebDriverWait` to wait for elements to be visible, clickable etc.
3. Locators need to be improved.
   The following code should be better:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
import os

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

os.environ['WDM_LOG_LEVEL'] = '0'
s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(s=path, options=chrome_options) # if you have problems with line 15
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

# Setting
classified_link = 'https://classifieds.ksl.com/search/Furniture'
time_to_wait_between_checking = 15


def get_first_listing():
    driver.get(classified_link)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#onetrust-close-btn-container button.onetrust-close-btn-handler"))).click() #close the cookies banner
    title_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".item-info-title-link a")))
    link = title_element.get_attribute('href')
    title = title_element.text
    return (link, title)


listing_info = get_first_listing()
first_listing_link_temp = listing_info[0]
listing_title = listing_info[1]

print(f"First Listing Title: {listing_title}, Link: {first_listing_link_temp}")

check_count = 0
active = True
while active:
    check_count += 1
    time.sleep(time_to_wait_between_checking)
    print(f"Checking to see if new listing, this is attempt number {check_count}")
    new_listing_info = get_first_listing()
    first_listing_link = new_listing_info[0]
    title = new_listing_info[1]
    if first_listing_link_temp != first_listing_link:
        print(f"There is a new ad. Title {title}, Link: {first_listing_link}")
        active = False
        break
```

Here I fixed `get_first_listing()` method only, not continued to the `while` loop